# javascript array - increment value at given key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a dynamic array and I am trying to increment the value by 1 if the key exists in the array. According to my debug it is incrementing the key and and creating a second key/value pair.

A snippet of my code:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            console.log(choices[i]);
            if (choices[i].YearTermId == 1) {
                if (!lookup(firstChoice, choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId)) {
                    firstChoice.push({
                        key: choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId,
                        value: 1
                    });
                } else {
                    firstChoice[choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId] = firstChoice[choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId] + 1;
                }
```

more if/else..

```
    function lookup( arr, name ) {
        for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
            if( arr[ i ].key === name )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You're using an array where you should be using an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an array where you should be using an object. If you use an object, your code can be rewritten as:

```
var firstChoice = {};

for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    var firstChoiceOptionId = choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId;

    if (choices[i].YearTermId == 1) {
        firstChoice[firstChoiceOptionId] = firstChoice[firstChoiceOptionId]
                ? firstChoice[firstChoiceOptionId] + 1
                : 1;

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

If you need the data as an array afterwards, just map it:

```
var firstChoiceArray = Object.keys(firstChoice).map(function(key) {
    return {
        key: key,
        value: firstChoice[key]
    };
});
```

Conversely, if you have an input array and want to convert it to an object for manipulation, reduce it:

```
var firstChoice = firstChoiceArray.reduce(function(result, current) {
    result[current.key] = current.value;

    return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: I am trying to keep it as an array key/value so I can plug the data into chart.js after

Comment: Just map it to an array after you're done with your manipulation. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should increment `value` key, like:

```
firstChoice[choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId].value ++;
```

And I would like to rewrite this code to:

```
var firstChoice = {};
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].YearTermId == 1) {
        if (!firstChoice[choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId]) {
            firstChoice[choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId] = 0;
        }
        firstChoice[choices[i].FirstChoiceOptionId]++;
    }
}
console.log(firstChoice);
```

Comment: I want to start the value at 1 - I am trying to plug in the array to chart.js after. When I use the first snippet, .value, cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Array.map`:
Example:

```
var a = [{key:"ab","value":1},{key:"cd","value":1},{key:"ef","value":1}];
a.map(function(item){if(item.key == this){item.value++}}, "cd");
```

So, a[1] will have value 2 after that.